# Inject DC into output side of laptop power supply?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, laptop

I have a HP omen laptop that operates on a 200 W 19.5 V power supply. I am currently lucky enough to live a nomadic life in a solar-powered travel trailer and try to run all my devices on DC rather than use my inverter.

I have been unable to find a commercially made DC-DC power supply for the laptop so I have therefore tried to create my own. It was not difficult to set up a separate DC-DC power supply to output 19.5 V at the required amperage, but because the laptop uses a third communication wire to identify the PSU, it will not charge.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but it appears it would be difficult to trick the sensing wire into thinking my homemade power supply was a good fit for the laptop.

I am therefore thinking of wiring my DIY 19.5 V power supply in parallel to the output of the original power supply with the sensing wire still connected. In this configuration, I would *not* plug in the AC side off the original PSU.

I am hoping that, if the DC side of the original power supply receives power injected from the output, it will power up the sensing wire tricking my laptop to using my DC-DC power supply.

Could this experiment end up ruining my original AC adapter?

Is there a chance it could work?

Anyone have any better solutions?

It is frustrating because the laptop clearly does not need 200 W to charge but yet won’t charge unless it has the oversized PSU which is only necessary when the GPU works hard. I would be satisfied if I could just charge it via DC-DC then need to resort to AC and my inverter off I need full power.

Comment: It will likely damage the orginal supply. Outputs are not supposed to be connected together, not even while unpowered. Can't you get a 12v input car charger? Or another mains adapter, maybe broken, which you can use to replicate the communication/sense wire?

Comment: Could you tell us the model of the power supply?

Comment: An AC inverter and the original power brick will most likely be your most flexible and least costly solution.

Comment: Can you access the third wire when you connect the original charger? Hopefully it's just a linear voltage, or logic level from the BMS of the laptop's batteries. It may even be a simple jumper to GND or to the battery pack. You may need a storage scope to see if there is some sort of communication going on between charger and battery.

Answer (score 2):

The HP power supply (PS) *does not continuously draw 200 watts*. It is a *switching* PS, and wastes comparatively little power. If the notebook is fully changed, standby power drawn from the AC mains is likely closer to 10 or 20 W, not 200. You can [buy a wattmeter](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=wattmeter) for US$10 to measure the actual power consumption of the PS under varying conditions.

It is doubtful you could find or make a power supply that is much more efficient. Though there *is* some loss of efficiency in first converting 12 VDC from the battery to 120 (or 240) VAC, before the HP PS, it avoids the issue of having to construct a separate supply for each device.

*Do* shut the 12 VDC-to-mains inverter when not in use, though.